# Carousel bootstrap 4 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've run into a problem with the carousel module on bootstrap 4. 
I've been troubleshooting for a long time but I'm getting nowhere so I'm just gonna try and ask here, I hope you guys can help me!

(I already checked out other posts on this topic but no luck so far)

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    //options here
    });
});
    </script>

<body>

 <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide span12" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="sfeer-kok-groente-snijden_5.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/diamond.png" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="#" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        Holder.addTheme("thumb", {background: "#55595c", foreground: "#eceeef", text: "Thumbnail"});
    });
</script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What has mysql tag to do in your question?

Answer (score 6):

I see two main problems:

First, you seem to be missing the bootstrap CSS class. Add it in your `<head>` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

According to the Bootstrap documentation:

> Add our JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Tether near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag. Be sure to place jQuery and Tether first, as our code depends on them.

In the `<head>` tag, you're loading, in order,

1. (CDN) Twitter Bootstrap
2. (Local) bootstrap.js (which I'm guessing refers to Twitter Bootstrap),
3. (CDN) jQuery 2.1.4

At the bottom of the `<body>` tag, you're loading, in order,

1. (CDN) jQuery 3.1.1
2. (Local) jQuery (only if the CDN didn't respond successfully)
3. (CDN) Tether
4. (Local) Holder
5. (Local) Twitter Bootstrap
6. An IE10 viewport bug workaround

Essentially, remove the `<script>` lines in the `<head>`, moving the carousel instantiation to the bottom. Your code will look similar to below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide span12" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="row">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="sfeer-kok-groente-snijden_5.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/diamond.png" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="#" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        Holder.addTheme("thumb", {
            background: "#55595c",
            foreground: "#eceeef",
            text: "Thumbnail"
        });
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            // Options
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this and another answer both use "#myCarousel" as the jquery selector, yet this isn't what's it's actually called in the sample code. It's called "carouselExampleIndicators". For future googlers, just make sure those match.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you might have misplaced some jQuery files and it is causing the issue, try to follow this way

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide span12" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="First slide">
                </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While i was doing carousel in bootstrap 4, i was facing the same problem.

I can see that you have mentioned `<ol class ="carousel-indicators">`

Here is the solution, just by changing ol to ul, you get the carousel ouput and rest all remains same.

`<ul class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>`

This link below might help you

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's trying to add a bootstrap carousel to a react project.

Go to the index.html file in the public folder.

And add the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```